# SignatureDoesNotMatch AWS With Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have a problem to list files from my bucket in S3 using Laravel 5.1.
When I try , it returns the message " SignatureDoesNotMatchThe signature request, calculated does not match the signature you provided. Make sure your key and signature ." I tested this on a Java class and return Ok .
Below my setup .

```
' S3 ' = > [
' Driver ' => ' s3 '
' Key ' => env ( ' S3_KEY ' ) ,
' Secret' = > env ( ' S3_SECRET ' ) ,
" Region " = > env ( ' S3_REGION ' ) ,
' Bucket ' => env ( ' S3_BUCKET ' ) ,
' Scheme ' => ' http '
]
:: Storage disk ( s3 ) -> files ( )
```

Any idea ?

Comment: That is some *bizarre* coding style. http://weknowmemes.com/generator/uploads/generated/g1379092610384759364.jpg Does your employer pay per space in your code or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

env ( ' S3_KEY ' )

remove the spaces

env ( 'S3_KEY' )

Comment: Yep, that's almost certainly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

even for the DO default region, we should use us-east-1. It will solve this error.